# Converting Field Data Type From Number to Text

Tags: fields

Just a question, will there be any data loss if a field with number type is converted to a text type? I've read from Salesforce help documentation that **changing to Number from any other type** can cause data loss. But how about vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=notes_on_changing_custom_field_types.htm&type=5) there is no mention of data loss when you change the type from number to text.

So this type of conversion shouldn't cause any data loss. Also a number can have **numbers** and **decimal character**. Which the text field will also have,i.e. a text field can have alphanumeric and special characters both. So there seems no scope of data loss in this case.

You can give this a try yourself in some dev org.

Comment: Will definitely give this one a try in my dev org. Thanks a lot!